# Android: Is GridLayout is suitable for this design

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application, I have to show some persons information. I have to show only three members at a time. On Swipe left to right i have to show another three set of members. Here is the design [image]

First I thought , we can use three List Views namely LV1,LV2,LV3
and set a List adapter for these 3 listviews. And In the ListAdapter the first row of the listview can take the Title details and afterwards it takes an Listviews for the successive rows. i.e Every White box has individual Listview we cant predict how many white boxes exists for one member.

I can send one object called Member for one listView and One of the attributes of the member object is ArrayList 
ie

```
 List mem1 = new ArrayList();
mem1.add(member1)
List mem2 = new ArrayList();
mem2.add(member2)
List mem3 = new ArrayList();
mem3.add(member3)
```

I can send mem1 for LV1 adapter and mem2 for LV2 adapter and mem3 for LV3 adapter

But I cant populate project details in the white boxes.

Please provide me the best way to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,

I consider three listviews and create custom view for listview . Here the listview contains only one row. the design of that row is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="27dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button_bg"
        android:text="action"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ttt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="27dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/projects"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true" >
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you put a List view in the form.Then create a seperate **"row.xml"** layout as a row of list view .
The **row.xml** contains **3 text boxes.**

For the heading you create a text view and put in the form.Then u should populate the list view based on below coding snippet

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        ArrayList items;

        MyAdapter(ArrayList items) {
            super(OrderSummary.this, R.layout.row, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            //Your business login to insert data in the text boxes
        }
    }

MyAdapter mSchedule = new MyAdapter(mylist);
listView.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest i got the solution